# filter by subdocument while showing all parent document mongoose mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is the schema model

```
const tokoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
    product: [{display: Boolean}]
}
```

So, what I want is filtering the data by `product.display`. When I filtered it using `toko.find({"product.display": true})` it only shows list of toko that has `product.display: true` but what I want is if the product display is false it keep showing the `_id` and `name` of toko with empty array of product `[]`. Example query expected

```
// showing all tokos
[
  {
   _id: blabla
   name: "test",
   product: [{_id: blabla, display: true}], // filter display:true
   },
   {
   _id: blabla,
   name: "test",
   product: [] // no product with display:true
   }
 ]
```

example of `toko.find({"product.display": true})` query

```
// not showing all tokos
[
  {
   _id: blabla
   name: "test",
   product: [{_id: blabla, display: true}]
   },
 ]
```

any solution for this? should I use aggregate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) for an array:

```
db.toko.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            product: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$product",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: [ "$$this.display", true ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y8ZuRaMQfv9)